# Apple Watch App Only Showing Clock

Tags: xcode, storyboard, apple-watch

Xcode states that the Apple Watch is running but yet I only see the clock. My storyboard interface should have a green background. There is nothing showing up in the slog.

```
- (void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {
    [super awakeWithContext:context];
NSLog(@"hello world");
}
```

Comment: Looks like for some reason your interface from storyboard isn't loaded. Can you show is some code and storyboard image? Is interface set as main interface in the storyboard?

Comment: Interesting...in the build phases section, the interface.storyboard is red and not showing the icon. How do I solve that? I have tried re-adding but it results in the same red result.

Comment: Looks like your storyboard file is misplaced?

Comment: I re-added it and that seemed to fix that issue. Now I just have an endless spinner and the storyboard still isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting and re-adding the storyboard into the app section, the NSLog now shows results again and the apple watch is showing the storyboard again.